# Manage.py sqlall doesn't create tables for models in my app

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to create a table for my models in my app, apparently the "python manage.py sqlall myapp" doesn't work

I tried using the "python manage.py sqlmigrate myapp", i still get errors

what is the proper command to use?

i am using django 1.11.7
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sqlmigrate` command just prints out the SQL for the migration, it does not run it. You should run `migrate` to make the changes.

See the [Migrations docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#the-commands) for more information about the migration commands.

The `sqlall` command was [removed in Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-9) at the same time as `syncdb` was removed.

Comment: i used the python "manage.py migrate myapp" and it worked, , there was a prompt asking me to run the command "manage.py makemigrations" and there was no migrations to apply,  so i had to do that first,  thanks all the same